# Check out this code

Tags: java, execution

I need a help to to find the error in my code and fix it.
Here is the code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Random r = new Random();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            Fighter f1 = new Fighter();
            Fighter f2 = new Fighter();
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the first fighter:");
            String str=s.nextLine();
            f1.name=str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            System.out.println("Choose the style:\n1/ Boxing\n2/ Kick Boxing\n3/ MMA");
            int style1 = s.nextInt();
            switch (style1){
                case 1 :f1 =new Boxer();
                    break;
                case 2 :f1 = new Kickeboxer();
                    break;
                case 3 :f1 = new MMA_Fighter();
                break;}
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the seconde fighter:");
            String str1=s.nextLine();
            f2.name=str1;
            System.out.println("Choose the style:\n1/ Boxing\n2/ Kick Boxing\n3/ MMA");
            int style2 = s.nextInt();
            switch (style2){
                case 1 :f2 = new Boxer();
                    break;
                case 2 :f2 = new Kickeboxer();
                    break;
                case 3 :f2 = new MMA_Fighter();
                break;}
            for (int rnd=1;rnd <=5;rnd++){
                f1.punch=r.nextInt(f1.power);
                f2.punch=r.nextInt(f2.power);
                f1.hp-=f2.punch;
                f2.hp-=f1.punch;
                if (f1.hp <= 0){
                    System.out.println("Round "+rnd+" result:\n K.O !");
                    break;
                }else if (f2.hp <= 0){
                    System.out.println("Round "+rnd+" result:\n K.O !");
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Round "+rnd+" result:\n"+f1.name+"'s health : "+f1.getHp()+"\n"+f2.name+"'s health : "+f2.getHp()+"\n    **********");}
            if (f1.hp>f2.hp){
                System.out.println(f1.name+" wins !");
            }else if(f1.hp<f2.hp){
                System.out.println(f2.name+" wins !");
            }else {System.out.println("It's a DRAW !");}
        }//end for
    }}
class Fighter {
        String name;
        int hp;
        int power;
        int punch;
        public int getHp() {
            return hp;
        }
}
class Boxer extends Fighter{
    int hp = 100;
    int power = 20;
}
class Kickeboxer extends Fighter{
    int hp =80;
    int power = 40;
}
class MMA_Fighter extends Fighter{
    int hp = 70;
    int power = 50;
}
```

When executing it, it gives me an error

> ```
> Enter the name of the first fighter: 
> Choose the style: 1/ Boxing 2/ Kick Boxing 3/ MMA 
> Enter the name of the seconde fighter: 
> Choose the style: 1/ Boxing 2/ Kick Boxing 3/ MMA
>
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException     at
>  java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)     at
>  java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)     at
>  java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)  at
>  java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)  at Main.main(Main.java:26)
> ```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some complementary 

debugging techniques.

Comment: @IvanPronin I think you forgot the complementary debugging techniques...

Comment: Did you try to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 0):

You get a `InputMismatchException` because you call `s.nextInt()`, but the input could not be parsed as an `int`. User may have typed other characters besides just numbers. You can make your interface more user friendly by catching this exception.

```
boolean choseStyle = false;
while (!choseStyle) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Choose the style:\n1/ Boxing\n2/ Kick Boxing\n3/ MMA");
        int style2 = s.nextInt();
        choseStyle = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `s.nextInt();` the scanner object only reads the integer part of the line, but it doesn't consider the carriage return. So when you invoke the next `s.nextLine()` it isn't reading the next line, actually is reading the reminder of the integer read before (the carriage return). 
So to clean the "garbage" of the line, just add an `s.nextLine();` after each `nextInt();`

```
int style2 = s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
```

You'll have an IllegalArgumentException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

Because of things related to inheritance I could see in your classes (Boxer, Kickboxer and MMA_Fighter).

To fix it I recommed to you do this:

```
class Fighter {
    String name;
    int hp;
    int power;
    int punch;

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

}

class Boxer extends Fighter {
    int hp = 100;
    int power = 20;

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }
}

class Kickeboxer extends Fighter {
    int hp = 80;
    int power = 40;

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }
}

class MMA_Fighter extends Fighter {
    int hp = 70;
    int power = 50;

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }
}
```

There's another way to resolve this, but for now I think it will work.
to learn more of inheritance check this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html